# why this calculation results in NaN?

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
var player = {
    x : 10.0,
    y : 10.0,
    color : "blue",
    v : 5.0,
    size : 10,
    render : function (c) {
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fillRect(Math.round(this.x), Math.round(this.y), this.size, this.size);
    }
};

function update(delta) {
    player.x += player.v * (delta / 1000);
    console.log("px = " + player.x);
}

function mainLoop(timeStamp) {
    delta = timeStamp - lastFrameTime;
    lastFrameTime = timeStamp;
    /* measure frame rate */
    curFps = Math.round((1/delta)*1000);

    /* game logic */
    update(delta);
    render();

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

The update() function is called every frame when position of the player needs to be updated. value of delta is ~16.00 (time in ms).
Why the value of player.x shows as NaN when printed?

Comment: Probably `player.v` or `delta` is `undefined`. What are the values, if you log them?

Comment: Show how you call `update`....

Comment: You should check `delta` variable, I had run your code with passing `delta = 16` and `console.log("px = " + player.x);` show log normally

Comment: I tried printing delta as well, it is printing correct values. If I use 16 instead of delta it works fine.

Comment: Maybe you are starting with `lastFrameTime` undefined, this becomes a NaN at `timeStamp - lastFrameTime`, which is propagated.

Comment: This is getting tedious. The problem is obviously due to a value not being a number (my money is on `delta`) and until you show how it is assigned a value, including how other variables (`timeStamp`, `lastFrameTime`) are assigned, we are all just guessing

Comment: I added more logs to see if some variables are `NaN`. Turns out, that the `timeStamp` argument passed to mainLoop() is `NaN` once, that caused the delta to be NaN and eventually `player.x` becomes `NaN`. Any more updates to `player.x` results in `NaN`. I am still wondering why callback given in  `requestAnimationFrame` gets `NaN` argument? Also, I don't see why this question got downvoted. care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

Your first loop iteration won't have `lastFrameTime` initialized to zero, it will be undefined. Number - undefined = NaN. Declare lastFrameTime at the top of your program as 0:

```
var lastFrameTime = 0;
```

Right now it's an implicit global, meaning because you never defined it with `var`, it's an accidental global variable that javascript is creating inside the loop.

Comment: Wouldn't OP be seeing *"ReferenceError: lastFrameTime is not defined"* or something similar in their console?

Comment: Only the first time, and if this code is running once every 16ms it could easily be missed with all of the other console.log chatter.

Comment: I'm seeing it every iteration

Comment: Also, as his code is written right now, setting it to 0 would be... not ideal.  It appears he's using timestamp, which I assume to mean unix timestamp (seconds, or more likely milleseconds, since epoch 1970), which means his very first update will be a HUGE delta, and a HUGE move of the character.

Comment: @Phil: Depends on the JavaScript engine that's executing it I guess. I do see that in Firefox, but in Chrome I get a different (although similar) answer.  IE gives me 'lastFrameTime' is undefined, but without knowing more about the code and what browser it's being run in, I still think this is the best answer.

Comment: I did initialize the lastFrameTime to 0. So, in first frame, the delta might be incorrect value, but it should not be NaN. I also tried skipping first frame to see if it helps. No help, i still see the px to be NaN.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be the first time the code runs, lastFrameTime isn't defined, and so delta = timestamp - <undefined>, which will result in delta being NaN, which will then result in player.x being incremented by NaN, turning it into NaN, which it will stay forever since we continue to increment it.

I think your fix is to either initialize lastFrameTime when your code starts (probably to the current timestamp), or alter main loop thusly

```
function mainLoop(timeStamp) {
    delta = timeStamp - lastFrameTime;
    lastFrameTime = timeStamp;
    if (!isNaN(delta)) {
        /* measure frame rate */
        curFps = Math.round((1/delta)*1000);

        /* game logic */
        update(delta);
        render();

        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
}
```

This will skipping the first, erroneous, game loop where delta is NaN.  On the second run through, lastFrameTime won't be undefined, delta will be created properly, and everything should work out.

If skipping the first loop isn't an option for whatever reason, just initialize lastFrameTime to something sane and everything should be ok.

Comment: I'd also go with `var delta = ...`. There's already too many globals :)

Comment: I did initialize the lastFrameTime to 0. So, in first frame, the delta might be incorrect value, but it should not be NaN. I also tried skipping first frame to see if it helps. No help, i still see the px to be NaN.

Comment: Then quite frankly I have no idea. I see your other comment saying that mainloop is called with NaN the first time through.  Are you sure this is due to a callback from requestAnimationFrame?  The reason I ask is because I've tested the code you've posted locally and it works perfectly (after having set lastFrameTime to 0 and removing the call to render).  Have you stepped through your code to make sure you aren't calling it from elsewhere accidentally?